# Dropdown goes behind QuickTime player

Tags: 2010, dropdown, video

I currently have a QuickTime player on my site just below the global navigation. When I hover over some of my dropdown navigation items, their dropdowns goes beneath the QuickTime player.

What would be a valid solution to this?

Comment: I suspect it is the same problem as with flash-movies in a page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123529/how-do-i-place-html-content-above-a-flash-movie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this by setting a higher CSS z-index on your drop down nav elements. Note that for better cross-browser compatibility, you should also assign a lower z-index to the QuickTime player itself. In some scenarios, z-index must be assigned on both elements to ensure they are layered consistently as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this response will be bereft of implementation specifics however I remember being briefed on a similar-sounding bug with drop-downs in I.E. falling behind in-line content. It was solved by placing the drop-down within a span element.